# How to convert the data stream to data set in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I need to convert the datastream to data set so that I could perform sorting operation on the data set. How to convert the data stream to dataset? Is it possible in flink?

Comment: Please revise your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Corrected spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to convert a `DataSet` into a `DataStream`. The APIs for batch and stream processing are separate. You can however, write the `DataStream` into a file and read the file as a `DataSet`.